# How to display a 3D text Using ARCore?

Tags: android, arcore

I'm trying to render a 3dText using ARCore library but unable to do so can anyone throw some light on it.

Comment: put your codes here .... what did you try ?

Comment: ever figure anything out? I want to do this same thing.

Answer (score 4):

ARCore does not provide any 3D rendering functionality. It only allows you to link virtual objects to real-world places. It gives you the current image from your camera and provides view and projection matrices to align your 3D world. But all rendering has to be done using OpenGL ES or some framework atop of it.

Comment: Good info, is there a recommended way to add/implement OpenGL ES to an arCore project to accomplish this? A reference perhaps?

Comment: The best way right now is to use [Google's Sceneform](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk) which provides an 3D engine that's nicely integrated with ARCore.